# igraph other names for edges

Tags: r, igraph, edges

I have an other question to: [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858377/how-can-i-access-the-epath-output-of-get-shortest-paths-to-get-the-edge-names/49192331?noredirect=1#comment85391572_49192331)

Is it in igraph possible to give other names for edges ("E1", "E2", "E3") than standart letters like "a","b","c"? And later create the shortest path output with them("E1","E2","E3")

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `name` attribute for the edges, and then specifying it in your plot statement, it would be better to use what igraph uses - the `label` attribute.

```
library(igraph)
solid = graph_from_literal(A-D,A-C,D-F,D-C,C-B,B-E)
E(solid)$label <- paste0("E", seq_len(ecount(solid)))
plot(solid)
```

[image: Solid]

This will allow you to get at the shortest paths as well. The `shortest_paths` function returns a structure that has the edgelist stored in `$epath`.  You can get the labels of the whole path from there

```
lapply(shortest_paths(solid, from='A', to ='F', output='epath')$epath, 
    function(x) { x$label })
[[1]]
[1] "E1" "E4"
```